# AdSense vs Cumulative Layout Shift (CLS)

Tags: responsive-design, adsense, cumulative-layout-shift

Any idea how to prevent the strange Cumulative Layout Shift (CLS) when page containing AdSense loads?

Website has a responsive design and use AdSense responsive ad units. Before implementing responsive design and using responsive ads there was not any problem because each ad position had defined fixed width and height.

See it live on the web https://cs.renault-club.cz/poradna
See it on YouTube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1pT4fWAtKfU